# how to use openipmp client (DRMPluginAll) in android file system(Ice Cream Sandwich)

Tags: android, drm

First of all i want to say that i have searched each and every forum to get the answer. And i already asked so many questions related to this question and i didn't get ant answer.

please atleast answer weather it's possible or not.

We want to write a DRMPlugin for android. I know it's possible we can write third party library. OpenIPMP open source available for DRM. It has a client DRMPluginAll.

I wanted to ask can i use that client directly in android file system as a DRM plugin.
May be some modification i have to do, but will it run on latest android file system like Ice Cream Sandwich or Gingerbread.

I have read that OpenIPMP last updated in 2006, so will it work with latest file system.

Wirting your own DRM Plugin is not a easy task, obviously you have to take some reference. I got this link, sample DRM plugin, i wanted to know what is the meaning of this

http://www.androidcodesearch.com/acs/source/frameworks/base/drm/libdrmframework/plugins/passthru/

can't i use it directly.

Thanks and please reply.

Comment: you could only add your code there if you build your own firmware. Distributing a plugin as an app is afaik not possible. You may be able to use the plugin code locally in your app but I don't know what your software does / requires.

Comment: hi zapl, thanks for your reply. Atleast somebody replied.

actually we have android application which is based on streaming concept. server is our own. We want to add encryption and decryption in streaming. For that we want to use DRM.Now to use DRM we have to add DRM plugin in our android file system which is gingerbread, Ice cream sandwich.

So i just want some reference, from where i should start.
i was thinking about to use OpenIPMP plugin. 

jsut for your information we will run this code on panda board. so can't we run this plugin in panda borad also.

Comment: Even my colleague asked same question on various forums.please see the link.http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/385218d2d2f2bbf7 Please suggest some solution.

Comment: I don't know how the DRM architecture is working and if / how you can extend it. There is some support for [Widevine](http://www.engadget.com/2010/12/05/google-spends-a-few-more-million-picks-up-widevine-drm-software/) drm in ICS now but I don't know if / how that can be used either.

Comment: thanks zapi, thanks for your reply. I'll search about Widevine. But please if you get any more information on this topic, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about searching using this URL:

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=+DRM+Client+for+Android&c=apps

I found many DRM client for Android here.   But you have to purchase the DRM server though.

Another opensource DRM is:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/drm/index.php?title=Main_Page

DRM for Android ICS:

http://www.prweb.com/releases/2012/2/prweb9210381.htm